# Data scrape script for telegram group

Tags: python, web-scraping, extract, telegram

This is the script I am using for data extraction from Telegram group. I want text message and User ID. I am downloading this information in CSV file. it is not showing any error so I do not what I am doing wrong.

```
import asyncio
import csv
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError

# Replace these with your own API credentials from https://my.telegram.org
api_id = #api_id
api_hash = '#api_hash'
phone = 'phone  number'

# Initialize the client
client = TelegramClient('telegram_session', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    try:
        # Connect to the Telegram server
        await client.connect()

        # Check if user is authorized, otherwise request authorization
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            await client.send_code_request(phone)
            code = input("Enter the code you received: ")
            try:
                await client.sign_in(phone, code)
            except SessionPasswordNeededError:
                password = input("Enter your account password: ")
                await client.sign_in(password=password)

        # Replace 'GROUP_NAME' with the group's name
        group = await client.get_entity('group name')

        # Open the CSV file for writing
        with open('group_messages.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['User ID', 'Message']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            # Write the header row
            writer.writeheader()

            # Iterate through messages and write them to the CSV file
            async for message in client.iter_messages(group, reverse=True):
                user_id = message.sender_id
                text = message.text

                writer.writerow({'User ID': user_id, 'Message': text})

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The above code showing no error and not giving the expected result it is just running in Pycharm.

Comment: please write expected result and actual result it gives.

Comment: As @BrijeshVarsani wrote, please include the actual result as to what happens when you run your script.